# How to call PHP function from other page?

Tags: php

i am currently working in our project which uses php.

i have this button

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <div class="profile" id="u118" style="left: 46px; top: 281px; width: 342px; height: 34px;">
    <input name="newOrder" type="submit" value="VIEW FULL COMPANY DETAILS" class="profile" id="profbutton" style="width: 342px; height: 34px;">
    </div>
</form>
```

and i want to call the php code from other file `testDisplayCompanyDetails.php`

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET[$_SESSION['id']]))
{
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
        $sql="Select * from company where CompanyID = :id";
        $res=$db->prepare($sql);
        $res->execute(array('id'=> $id));   
        while($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            echo $row['Name'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['Address'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['Telephone1'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['Telephone2'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BusinessWebsite'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BusinessEmail'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BusinessPermit'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BusinessPermitValidTill'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['DTIPermit'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['DTIPermitValidTill'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BankName'];
            echo "</br>";
            echo $row['BankAccountNumber'];
            echo "</br>";
        }
```

}
    ?>

how can i do this? i copied the wrong code. sorry

Comment: How about `<form method="post" action="displanamev1.php">`

Comment: There does not appear to be any direct relation between your form and the PHP that you say you want to run. Your form does not contain a field named `p_id`, which is used in the PHP code. Also, your PHP code is only fetching an individual's name, where your button indicates that you are wanting to get "full company details".

Comment: As C above except the mixing of POST of GET

Comment: i copied the wrong code. sorry

Answer (score 0):

In the form, the action needs to point to your file.

`<form action="/path/to/your/script.php" method="post">`

Also, your `method="post"` means that you need to use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET` - amd the `name` of your input will have to be the same as the key in the $_POST:

```
<?php
include 'dbconnection.php';

    if(isset($_POST['newOrder']))
    {
    $id = $_POST['newOrder'];
    $sqlLoader="Select Name from validpersonnel where PersonnelID = :id";
    $resLoader=$db->prepare($sqlLoader);
    $resLoader->execute(array('id' => $id));
    $row = $resLoader->fetch();
    echo $row['Name'];
    }
```

It will be a white screen with the value of `$row` unless you tell the PHP file to output more stuff.

Furthermore, you'll need an `<input type="submit"/>` in order to tell the browser to send the data in the input form --- or otherwise, you'll need a javascript handler.

If the output shouldn't be too intensive, you'll want to look into ajax - which will allow the data to be sent -- and will allow you to process the response without redirecting or reloading the page.

Also, you would be smart to understand how to prevent against injection by validating your $_POST inputs on the server-side.

Look into `filter_var` as a start -

for numbers: 
`filter_var($_POST['newOrder'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);` should suffice - 
Anything else, it gets a bit tricky - but i typically use: 
`filter_var($_POST['newOrder'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);` - which will cover basic needs.

Comment: Its the same deal - the answer stays the same -- mind your $_GET and $_POST

Comment: Use one or the other --- if `method="get"`, then your PHP should have `$_GET` -- if `method="post"` - your PHP should have `$_POST` --

Comment: can i apply filter_var in javascript function? i put popout box to ask the user some variable and then i pass it to other page. everytime i pass the variable i can see the said variable in redirecting the page

Comment: No, because a hacker will bypass any javascript validation.

Answer (score -1):

Try `action="displanamev1.php"` and change your `$_GET` in displanamev1.php to `$_POST` (or change `method="post"` to `method="get"`)